# Определить подключение usb-модема.

Tags: c#, usb, c++

Добрый день,

Нужно определить момент подключения usb-устройства (с этим проблем не возникает).
Далее мне необходимо идентифицировать тип устройства. Конкретнее мне нужно узнать, модем ли это, или нет.

Средства: с++, с#.

Comment: ЗДравствуйте. К сожалению, мы не можем по Вашему нику и топику определить КАК Вы определяете, КАКИМ языком+библиотекой/средствами Вы пользуетесь.

Comment: @Богдан Бессонов, нормальный вопрос.

Однако десятисекундное гугление помогло бы вам быстрее, чем здесь.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60579/A-USB-Library-to-Detect-USB-Devices

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6f074b3-31ae-4d9d-9aee-6eda728b17f6/detecting-usb-device-insertion-in-c

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6f074b3-31ae-4d9d-9aee-6eda728b17f6/detecting-usb-device-insertion-in-c

Comment: @Богдан Бессонов, всепокорнейше прошу меня простить за столь неоднозначный вопрос, как "Определить подключение usb-модема" - ведь он написан не на русском языке.
Да и фраза "Средства: с++, с#.", которая вообще, видимо, зашифрована была не даёт понятия о том, "КАКИМ языком+библиотекой/средствами Вы пользуетесь."

З.Ы. или вы не до конца читаете топики?

Comment: @Veikedo, спасибо за понимание, а то это был не первый форум, где люди (по всей видимости не дочитав до конца начинают ругаться).
Да что-то я не то в запрос поисковика вбивал=(
Однако, вскоре я нашёл сайт с данными о vid & pid всевозможных устройств.
Пользуясь ими теперь легко идентифицирую подключённое устройство.

З.Ы. Если кому-то вдруг понадобятся исходники - пишите на мыло.
З.З.Ы. e-mail: 96freemmy69@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определить тип устройства можно с помощью WMI-запроса к классу `Win32_PnpEntity`. Зная `DeviceID`, можно получить свойства `PnpClass` (текстовое имя класса устройств), `Service` (имя драйвера) и `ClassGuid` (идентификатор класса устройств), на основе которых можно судить о типе устройства. Например, для модемов

> PnpClass = Modem, ClassGuid = {4d36e96d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}

Пример кода на c# для вывода названия, DeviceID и PnpClass для всех USB-устройств:

```
using System.Management;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";

        ManagementObjectCollection collection;
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "root\\CIMV2",
            @"Select Caption,DeviceID,PnpClass From Win32_PnpEntity WHERE DeviceID like '%USB%'"))
            collection = searcher.Get();

        int i = 1;
        foreach (var device in collection)
        {
            textBox1.Text += "Device "+i.ToString()+": "+Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (var p in device.Properties)
            {
                textBox1.Text += p.Name + ": ";
                if (p.Value != null)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += p.Value.ToString();
                }
                else textBox1.Text += "null";

                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
            textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            i++;
        }            
    }

}
```

Выводит что-то такое:

> Device 1:
>   Caption: Корневой USB-концентратор (USB 3.0)
>   DeviceID: USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&1ED8C4AE&0&0
>   PNPClass: USB
>
> Device 2:
>   Caption: HUAWEI Mass Storage USB Device
>   DeviceID: USBSTOR\CDROM&VEN_HUAWEI&PROD_MASS_STORAGE&REV_2.31\7&11BA591D&0
>   PNPClass: CDROM
>
> Device 3:
>   Caption: HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G Modem
>   DeviceID: USB\VID_12D1&PID_1001&MI_00\6&4572B64&5&0000
>   PNPClass: Modem
>
> Device 4:
>   Caption: SAMSUNG Android USB Remote NDIS Network Device
>   DeviceID: USB\VID_04E8&PID_6881\1234567890ABCDEF
>   PNPClass: Net